# Python - get closest integer value sorted by musical notation

Tags: python, sorting

given a list of integers

```
values = [7, 9, 10, 11]
```

If I want to find the closest value to

```
value = 0
```

I could simply use

```
closest_value = min(values, key=lambda x:abs(x-value))
```

and get

```
[out]: 7
```

however, in my case `values` correspond to integers of musical notation, like so:

```
notation_values = {'C':0, 'C#':1, 'D':2, 'Eb':3, 'E':4, 'F':5, 'F#':6, 'G':7, 'Ab':8, 'A':9, 'Bb':10, 'B':11}
```

in which case, `0` is closer to `11`, because, `12` would be `'C'` again, only an octave higher.

how do I get the closest integer to `value` according to this logic?

Comment: Sounds like you want the closest value that is less than your index. IE: the closest value to 1 is 0, and the closest value to 0 is 11, based on your range. In that case, the index of the closest value should be something like "value - 1 % 12".

Comment: Is 11 as close to 0 as 13 is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want the closest value that is **less** than your index. IE: the closest value to 1 is 0, and the closest value to 0 is 11, and so on (based on your range [0-11]).

Try this:

```
closest_value = (value - 1) % 12
```

You should be able to use the result as an index to your notation_values so you can determine the corresponding musical note.